# Netbeans 12.3 contains files with errors badge

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, payara

I have web application java EE 7 and been developed  on Netbeans 12.3 and it give me contains files with errors badge at the same time it build and run successfully with no errors but in the project side in the netbeans it shows the badges. keeping in mind using payara 5.2020 as application server and java 8 jdk for the **netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291"**
just to clarify i have deleted the cache for netbeans and still the same issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpa1K.png)

any suggestion ??

Comment: [1] Sorry, but this is not at all clear to me: _"it give me contains files with errors bade at the same time it build and run successfully with no errors but in the project side in the netbeans it shows the badges"_. Please edit that to clarify your precise problem. [2] Adding a screen shot of the actual errors would also be helpful. [3] Also delete that [performance] tag, or explain why it is relevant for your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.